# Unable to Map local drive user domain changed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

Recently, my TFS server changed from **Physical** to **Virtual** by infrastructure team, and same time, they moved all users from one domain to another. Earlier, suppose, I connected to TFS and mapped to local drive with `domain1\user1`, new one is now `domain2\user1`.

I am able to connect to TFS, however; not able to map same drive which I earlier mapped using old drive.

Due to this, I am unable to `checkin` existing changes and mapping is not working.

What can be done in this situation to get mapped same local path along with existing checkouts by previous user.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run [Workspaces Command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54dkh0y3(v=vs.100).aspx) to update UserName:

```
tf workspaces [/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl] [/updateUserName:oldUserName]
```

`/updateUserName` option updates security identification information on the Team Foundation server for a user whose network user name has been changed.